# How to insert block at specific line number using ansible

Tags: docker, ansible, docker-daemon

I want to add below docker log rotation specs into daemon.json file using ansible-playbook

```
"log-driver": "json-file",
"log-opts": {
  "max-size": "1m",
  "max-file": "4"
}
```

What if daemon.json is already present on the node which I am applying the playbook to. I dont want to mess up existing configuration. How do I add above block at line no. 2 ( that is after '{' or before last line i.e. '}' ) ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use for blocks [blockinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html):

```yaml
- name: Add config to daemon.json
  ansible.builtin.blockinfile:
    path: "<location of the docker daemon.json>"
    insertafter: '\"log-opts\": {' # not sure about the escaping
    block: |
      "log-driver": "json-file",
      "log-opts": {
        "max-size": "1m",
        "max-file": "4"
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

**ansible.builtin.lineinfile**

- This module ensures a particular line is in a file, or replace an existing line using a back-referenced regular expression.
- This is primarily useful when you want to change a single line in a file only.

**ansible.builtin.blockinfile**

- This module will insert/update/remove a block of multi-line text surrounded by customizable marker lines.

As @malpanez explains, I think it would be more accurate to use the `ansible.builtin.blockinfile` module for this. You can look at the example usage from the link below.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lineinfile` module

```yaml
- name: Add logrotate to daemon.json
  lineinfile:
    path: "<location of the docker daemon.json>"
    insertafter: '\"log-opts\": {'         # not sure about the escaping
    line: <your custom line>
```